# Sign in to Google Play disappears after the green loading screen. How to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-console

When I click a button to sign in to Google Play User in my game that I created using Unity, it takes some seconds then a little screen containing "Google Play Jeux" appears then it starts loading and disappears like nothing happened without letting me sign in, any solution ? do i need to publish my game to make google play sign in work (currently im using an internal testers opt in link) ??

[image]

do i need to publish it to test sign in ??

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add screen captures that illustrate the problem?

Comment: @David Cullen , updated

Comment: I was hoping you would capture screen shots on your phone of each step in the process and that you would include multiple pictures in your answer. As things stand, there's not a lot of information here.

Comment: i think thats all what i can tell about my problem , click a button to sign in ---> the google play loading screen appears and disappears so the social.local user.authenticated returns false

Comment: Capture logs with logcat and see if anything is printed there. Double check your configuration of GPG. Ours works without publishing the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : to be sure the game u wanna test its google games services is right prepared follow this steps :

1-in Release management App releases upload your game to Internal testers or Alpha or Beta in Release management App releases and add testers emails.

2-also dont forget to go to Game services click on your game open Testing* window and add the same testers emails so they can test google play games services like sign in, leaderboards and achievements.

3- now you can give the link to the testers that you got from your game Release management/App release then in the one you did Internal test or Alpha or Beta  click Manage click Manage testers arrow in the right corner and copy that Opt-in URL , (also be sure to check the name of users testers u created before checkbox who is in the same window of the Opt-in URL)

yes no need to publish game to test play games services but be sure you did the step number 2

Also if you wanna publish your game to test it (internal test for example) make sure in https://console.developers.google.com/apis in "Credentials" page select your project and put SHA-1 certificate fingerprint code u copied from {App signing certificate} part in APP Signing in Release Management menu.

And if you wanna test the build directly to your phone before publishing it in google play for SHA-1 certificate fingerprint code u must copie the one in {Upload certificate} part